# Disconnect eclipse project from svn by code

Tags: eclipse, svn, disconnect

I called a method in eclipse through `REST` to invoke `SVNKitUtil` at the server side to delete the project from `SVN` by code.

And also I deleted `.svn` folder under this project, but the project is still linked with SVN in Eclipse.

What should I do to remove the link by code ? (not the directly operation in eclipse, I need to realize it by code.)